# Tratando datas para pesquisa no banco

Tags: php, mysql, sql, zend

Estou realizando a seguinte captura de uma data:

```
$dtInicial  = $this->_getParam('dataInicial'); // Padrão dd/mm/aaaa
```

Para efetuar busca no banco preciso deixa-la no padrão aaaa/mm/dd:

```
$dt1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dtInicial));
```

Porém se realizado a pesquisa do dia a mais que hoje não funciona, por exemplo: 
**25/12/2014 retorna "1969-31-12"**

E outro detalhe é que preciso fazer uma pesquisa entre uma data e outra, sei da utilização do between no sql, mas usando o ZF1 não sei bem,

```
 $select = $this->select();
        $select->where("data_prazo = ?", $dtInicial);
        $select->where("data_prazo = ?", $dtFinal);
```

Comment: Só para dizer que a código onde fazer pesquisa entre as datas deu certo assim: $select->where("data_prazo between '$dtInicial' and '$dtFinal'"); ;)

Comment: não sei a finalidade, mas já pensou em utilizar datas com o formato UNIX_TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a função `date()` esta considerando `m/d/Y`(Formato de data Americano), então quando você passa `25/12/2014`, o dia 25, na verdade, é considerado como mês 25, como mês 25 não existe a função retorna essa data default.

[Php Manual](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtotime.php#100144) Nesse comentário aqui do phpmanual é sugerido que você use `.` para tratar sobre datas no formato ISO(Y.m.d), porém, se desejar, você pode, também, usar `-`, pois o nosso formato de data é o Europeu(d-m-Y). Tanto o `.` quanto o `-` resolverão seu problema.

```
$dtInicial  = $this->_getParam('dataInicial');

$dt1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/",".",$dtInicial))); 
//Ou Formato Europeu
$dt1 = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$dtInicial)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo a utilização da classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php) do php;

```
$dtInicial  = $this->_getParam('dataInicial'); // Padrão dd/mm/aaaa
$objDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $dtInicial);

if ($objDate instanceof DateTime) {
  // Eh uma data
} else {
  // ops... nao eh uma data!
}
```